# Bootstrap - Unable to center collapsed items with NavBar pulled right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I have a standard Bootstrap collapsible `NavBar` that is `pulled-right`.

**The Issue:**

This is the `NavBar` on a non-mobile device:

[image]

This is pulled right to allow for this desired right-aligned posistion.

This is the `NavBar` collpased on a mobile device:

[image]

**Note that the item in the dropdown are aligned right, this make sense as its pulled right but I want them centered when on a mobile device, whilst keeping them aligned right on a non-mobile device

**The Code:**

I thought that setting `text-center` on the `<ul>` list would solve the issue but it does not:

```
        <div class="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarColour" role="navigation" id="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="~/Images/DC.png" class="dc">
                </div>
                <div class="middleNavPadding">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <div class="pull-right text-center">

                           ********Set text-center but this dosen't work********                                

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Info">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Mission">Our Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Gallery">Projects Gallery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Any help with setting these `<ul>` list elements centered but keep the menu items pulled right on a non mobile device would be great.

Comment: maybe css `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pull-right` you should use `navbar-right`.
Just put `navbar-right` to the `unordered-list`, remove the `pull-right` div, and the links will be centered on small devices.
Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wazaaaap/vw27qm4k/).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarColour" role="navigation" id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
                <img src="~/Images/DC.png" class="dc">
            </div>
            <div class="middleNavPadding">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Info">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Mission">Our Mission</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Gallery">Projects Gallery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Contact">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```